# symfony with Doctrine whith Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, doctrine

I have a procedure under SQL Server.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]
-- Variables d'entrée
@p_ENL_I_ID                 int,
-- Variables de retour
@p_RETURN_STATUS            int output
AS
BEGIN
if @p_ENL_I_ID >5   
begin
    SET @p_RETURN_STATUS= 6
end
else
begin
    SET @p_RETURN_STATUS=2
end
END
```

and my code for call this procédure :

```
$query = "{CALL TEST(:p_ENL_I_ID,  :p_RETURN_STATUS) }";
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$nativeQuery = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery($query, $rsm);
$nativeQuery->setParameters(array('p_ENL_I_ID'=> 8 ,'p_RETURN_STATUS' => '' ));
$result= $nativeQuery->getResult();
```

The procedure works, but I have an error: exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields

How to retrieve return variable `@p_RETURN_STATUS`?

Comment: Add Sql server to your question tag

Comment: Your calling code seems to be expecting query results; you could return one, just before the final  END as `SELECT @p_RETURN_STATUS as RETURN_STATUS.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]
-- Variables d'entrée
@p_ENL_I_ID                 int,
-- Variables de retour
@p_RETURN_STATUS            int output
AS
BEGIN
set nocount on
if @p_ENL_I_ID >5   
begin
    SET @p_RETURN_STATUS= 6
end
else
begin
    SET @p_RETURN_STATUS=2
end
SELECT @p_RETURN_STATUS as RETURN_STATUS;
END
```

Comment: it returns an empty array []

Comment: I think at some point you have to do a select @p_RETURN_STATUS in $query but I don't know how to articulate that.

Comment: sometimes the calling modules get confused because SQLServer returns messages like '(xxx rows affected)'; so I added a SET NOCOUNT ON (usual practice) to suppress those. Admittedly your proc does not perform any DML, but just in case.

Comment: no... I can test this : $query = "SELECT :p_RETURN_STATUS as 'RETURN_STATUS'; {CALL TEST(:p_ENL_I_ID,  :p_RETURN_STATUS )} ";  but it returns an empty array []

Comment: I think my problem comes from elsewhere.  If try this : $query ="SELECT '4' as result";
       $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
       $nativeQuery = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery($query, $rsm);  dd($nativeQuery->getResult());   it the same respons empty array [] normally it should return 4  ?